# Kit info missing for Crashlytics kit xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crashlytics

I tried to integrate Fabric in iOS project. I followed the steps from the tutorial:

1. Add a run script Build Phase
2. In AppDelegate.m

Implementation:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
    return YES;
}
```

3. Run project

However at last check application crashes:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Kit info missing for Crashlytics kit'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you follow the step of the Fabric app?  It does each step and won't proceed to the next step until you've completed the step.  It's actually pretty annoying as it dictates where the `.framework` files exist in the project tree, but you can always complete the installation and then move the frameworks somewhere sensible.

Answer (score 1):

You probably already imported these files, but for future readers, you should also have in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
```

You should also have `Fabric.framework` and `Crashlytics.framework` in your Frameworks (`project -> target -> link phases -> link binary with libraries`).

You should also have `Fabric RunScript` in `Link Phases`:

```
./app/path/Fabric.framework/run key1 key2
```

If you followed `Fabric.app` tutorial, you should have all these steps configured. Did you follow it? Fo you have all above items?

Comment: Make also sure you did not keep the old version of Crashlytics.framework somewhere in your project. Removing this outdated framework did the trick in my case.